# Specify Return URL for Devise Login as a Query String Parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Ruby on Rails, Using Devise for Authentication. I understand Devise contains out of the box deep linking, but it requires the User to first navigate to a URL that they need to be authenticated for.

This use case doesn't meet my needs, and I'm wondering whether there is an option to provide a query string parameter so that the user is redirected to the current page after signing in. Signing in adds functionality to the page, but isn't required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just extend the `Devise::SessionsController` to suit your need. If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L21), Devise uses `after_sign_in_path_for` to redirect the user to a specific path after a successful sign in.

Assuming the resource you have is a `User`

In your `routes.rb`, specify which router Devise should use:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: 'sessions'}
```

Then create a controller in `app/controllers/sessions_controller` that inherits from `Devise::SessionsController` and override the `after_sign_in_path_for`:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  protected

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)        
    params[:redirect_path].presence || stored_location_for(resource)
  end
end
```

In your new session form (`app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb`), add a hidden tag that relays the `redirect_path` param to the controller:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :redirect_path, params[:redirect_path].presence %>
```

Now if the user visits `new_user_session_path(redirect_path: some_path)`, they should be redirected to the desired path after a successful sign in.